# C# reading Database on Timer

Tags: c#, .net, sql, visual-studio, timer

I'm reading MSSQL database on every 10 minute and processing the data & uploading XML file generated from given data. Database is updated at every 8 minute at public domain. With in every timer call we receive around 1050-2000 data rows. Currently i'm using C# Timer to get and update and sync both local and remote database. Sometime the following code get unresponsive and hang-in between. Please provide the alternative for the following or any other logic that will work well in real time.

Code:

```
    System.Timers.Timer Timer =null;

    public void initModelViewer
    {
        Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        Timer.Interval = 1000*60*10;
        Timer.Enabled = true;    
        Timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
        Timer.Start();
    }


    void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
       try
      {
          lock (this)
        {
            #region GetCustIRDI
            DataSet DsIRDIModel = DbManager.GetDatasetByCommand(cSQL.getIRDIInfo("SQL Command"));
            //Process the information.
            //update the client side application.
            #endregion

            #region GetCustIRDIXML
            DataSet DsIRDIXMLModel = DbManager.GetDatasetByCommand(cSQL.getIRDIXML("SQL Command"));

            //Generate and save the XML. Another app upload it
            XMLAPPFabicModel FabricXML = new XMLAPPFabicModel(DsIRDIXMLModel, XMLSpecs.Limitation));

            //Fabric EventHandlers...

            //Sync the local DBFabricModel and update main server
            #endregion
        }
}catch(Exception ex){
 //Error handling 
}


    }
```

Comment: Why not use a windows service that 'sleeps' for a predefined period after the processing has completed. With your timed approach you may run into concurrency issues.

Comment: Yes, you are right,timer enable and disable will solve my problem and it will work systematically but i can't have delay in between. sometime system wait more than 15 min to finish the entire process. Can background thread provide any help?

Comment: You could always use the TaskManager (4.0) or a thread pool to spread the workload, aka vertical scaleing. If you wanted horizontal scaleing then simply have several machines that all have the windows service but only operate on a predefined set of records. Server A processes record id's 0 to 1000 Server B processes records 1001 to 2000 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

First, as i know, do not use synchronising with "this" keyword.
Instead of, use:

```
private readonly object _sync;
```

Second, i do not know your objects (XMLAPPFabicModel , DbManager), but if you want debug it, you need use one by one objects.

For example, in debug scenario 1 use only

```
            DataSet DsIRDIModel = DbManager.GetDatasetByCommand(cSQL.getIRDIInfo("SQL Command"));
```

In scenario 2 use only:

```
XMLAPPFabicModel FabricXML = new XMLAPPFabicModel(DsIRDIXMLModel, XMLSpecs.Limitation));
```

with some DsIRDIXMLModel object.

Third, why do you need the DsIRDIModel  object?